# How do I toggle a firebase realtime database mode from locked to test?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I setup a firebase project that uses a realtime database. While setting it up, I selected locked mode. I can alter the read and write values to true but it automatically changes them back to false. There also does not seem to be a feature to delete the database under the Spark plan. How do I set the mode to test mode without starting the whole project from scratch?

Comment: What do you mean "automatically changes them back to false"?  If you change the rules, that should be permanent until you change them again.  Any other behavior would be a huge bug.

Comment: @DougStevenson Firebase automatically changes the .read and .write values for my database to false every so often, I cannot say how frequent exactly but it occurs every other hour or so.

Comment: If you are certain that you're not doing that (which you could be with the Firebase CLI using `firebase deploy`), you should contact Firebase support for help. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson I was unaware `firebase deploy` did that. Do you know if databases that start in test mode have the same behavior where `.read` and `.write` are set to false after deploy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're accidentally resetting your security rules with the Firebase CLI when you run `firebase deploy`.  If you selected "Realtime Database" when you ran `firebase init`, that would create a database.rules file in your project directory with the current set of rules for your project.  When you run `firebase deploy`, that will deploy whatever rules you have in that file, **overwriting any changes you might have made in the console**.

You will need to be careful about this.  It might be helpful to read more about how to work with the CLI, including use of the `--only` flag to determine which product information should be deployed.  You might also want to commit to never making changes to rules in the console, and instead use the CLI for everything.